# Як можна неформально звернутись до групи людей?

Tags: вживання-слів

Чи є якісь усталені способи звертатися до не специфічної групи людей в неофіційному середовищі, наприклад, до перехожих на вулиці?

У якості формальних або урочистих звертань до багатьох людей водночас часто використовуються наступні вирази: "шановні добродії та добродійки", "пані та панове".

В художній літературі зустрічаються варіанти "товариство", "шановні", "друзі", "люди".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Зі [словопедії](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53407/26584.html):

> За більшовицьких часів універсальною формою звертання було слово
> **товариш**. Щоправда, як в усній, так і в письмовій формах воно
> постійно еволюціонувало: "**т.** Вухналь", "**тов.** Вухналь", "**товариш** Вухналь Йосип Васильович". Усі різновиди прийнятої норми варіювалися
> залежно від того, хто і на якому щаблі стояв.
>
> Зі словом **громадянин** частіше зверталися до тих, кого позбавляли
> громадянських прав або ж щоб дистанціюватися.
>
> Лексемою **добродій**
> краще було не послуговуватися, бо тоді людину сприймали як причетну до
> колишньої Директорії...
>
> Слово **мадам** було лайливе. Ним обзивали, коли
> хотіли натякнути на сумнівні морально-етичні якості особи. Таке
> зміщення понять у вживанні слів-звертань, та ще й узятих з чужих мов,
> створило свій макаронічний стиль, щось на зразок "Эй, девушка в
> светлой кофточке!", "Эй, мужчина в темной шляпе!"
>
> Незрідка доводилося спостерігати, як до незнайомих зверталися **"ніяк"**,
> тобто ставили запитання, висловлювали міркування начебто безадресно, у
> простір з надією, що хтось прийме це "на себе" і відповість чи
> втягнеться в розмову.
>
> Лише на початку 90-х років лаконічне, милозвучне і найбільш відповідне
> саме українській спільноті звертання **пан, пані, панове** стало начебто
> набувати прав громадянства. Ці слова з притаманним їм
> стримано-емоційним і водночас найповнішим виявленням поваги зазвучали
> у побуті, в офіційних стосунках, у інших сферах.
>
> У документах форма **пан** уживається з ім’ям, прізвищем, назвою посади,
> тобто порівняно з добродій має виразне забарвлення офіційності. А до
> колективу людей, до аудиторії слухачів варто звертатися: *панове*,
> *шановні пані й панове*, *шановне товариство*, *вельмишановне зібрання*.

**Панове** - це звертання до сукупності людей як винятково чоловічої статі, так і статево змішаної. *Пані та панове* є перекладом *Mesdames et messieurs*. З точки зору української мови - це тавтологія, щось на кшталт *жінки та люди*.

Є інша думка, що *панове* - це кличний відмінок слова *пани́*, а, отже, звертатись можна так лише до сукупності людей винятково чоловічої статі:

```
називний пан пани́   
родовий па́на пані́в  
давальний па́нові, па́ну пана́м   
знахідний па́на пані́в  
орудний па́ном пана́ми  
місцевий на/у па́нові, па́ну на/у пана́х  
кличний па́не пани́, пано́ве
```

Хоча в більшості обговорень схиляються до думки, до *пано́ве* - не лише кличний відмінок слова *пани́*, але й і власна назва, іменник.

У творах класиків, зокрема Шевченка й Нечуя, можна побачити звертання *панове громадо* – свідчення того, що вживатися воно могло не лише щодо чоловіків, а й до чоловічо-жіночого товариства.

Уривок з "Украденого щастя" Івана Франка:

> – Знаєте ви що, **панове свiдки**, я тут хочу з Миколою розумне слово
> говорити. Вас тут не потрiбно. Може б, ви пiшли собi до дiдька? (...)
> **Селяни i селянки** сквапно виходять. Декотрi хрестяться i плюють.

Хоч, з іншого боку, навіть коли в громаді чи серед свідків і були жінки, то зовсім не означало, що звертаються і до жінок. Кажучи *панове громадо*, *панове свідки*, *панове товариство*, адресувати ті слова промовці могли, звісно, тільки чоловікам, жіноча ж частина могла слугувати за "непомітне тло" чи "покірну масу". Нині ж, коли жінки є рівними в правах з чоловіками, традиційне звертання панове громадо/товариство, безумовно, [стосується](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/lofiversion/index.php?t2374.html) представників обох статей.

Колишній Президент України Віктор Ющенко використовував звернення *любі друзі*. Проте завдяки широкій популярності і комедійним пародіям цей вираз, по суті, перетворився на [мем](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BC), а, отже, вживається переважно в іронічному контексті.

Comment: Типове неформальне звертання до групи людей дещо різниться між регіонами України.

_На заході_ переважно вживають слово "**панове**" і це вважається оптимальним звертанням до групи людей, до яких по окремості зверталися б на Ви. 
В більш неформальних випадках можна вживати слово "**народ**" (скажімо попросити розступитися студентів під аудиторією, чи потіснитися людей у маршрутці).

_В центральних і південних областях_ можуть частіше використовувати   в неформальній ситуації просто звертання "**люди**" або "**колеги**".

Answer (score 2):

Звернення `панове` на мою думку є дость нейтральним щодо формальності, але, зауважу, не гендеру. Порівняйте з [państwo](https://pl.wiktionary.org/wiki/pa%C5%84stwo), яке в польскій мові використовується поміж іншого і для звернення до групи людей

Comment: "Шановне панство" теж можна часто зустріти.