# Як звернутися до змішаної групи молодих людей (аналог рос. "ребята")?

Tags: переклад, from-russian, росіянізм

Хоча в російській мові слово *ребята* застосовується при зверненні до групи хлопців, часто можна почути, як у нас його використовують при зверненні до змішаної групи (хлопців та дівчат). Але ж це слово є калькою.

Який україномовний аналог найкраще підходить при зверненні до змішаної групи молодих людей?

Comment: Не думаю, що це можна назвати калькою. Це просто іншомовне слово чи суржик

Comment: Так кажуть *реб'ята* чи *рєбята*? Бо якщо друге, тоді дійсно суржик, як вірно завважив @maccstax

Comment: Я чув _рєбята_. Чи є хороший україномовний аналог?

Comment: Якщо до змішаної групи, то тут проблема, вдалого сучасного відповідника важко знайти.
Братчики, друзі, товариші - залежить від контексту.

Comment: панство, товариство, якщо зовсім неформально то чуваки

Comment: Related, nearly duplicate of: http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/231/

Comment: @bytebuster  тут все ж **до молодих**. Не уявляю, щоб я до групи 15-річних звертався як *панове*.

Comment: напевно це будет **хлопці**

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick, мова йде про *змішану* групу людей.

Comment: @user2513149 *Друзі*, менш формально - *друзяки*. Як варіант.

Answer (score 16):

Поверхневий пошук приніс наступні варіанти з [цього джерела](http://ua-referat.com/%D0%97%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96):

- у розділі про нейтральні форми звертання наводиться такий приклад:

  > При зверненні до групи людей часто використовувалася і просто форма **люди** (люде).
- згадуються наступні варіанти з публіцистичних текстів:

  > *... адресації групи людей (**Дівчата**, минуло разу ви пріїжджалі з концертом ...; **Хлопці**, Перш за все, від імені усіх майданівців хотілося бі подякувати ...) є очевидним елементом розмовного стилю, до того ж підкреслюють солідарність говорить з адресатом, тому що такі форми вибиралися для звернення до членів музичного колективу, тобто позбавлені прямої вказівки на вік*.
- наводяться також приклади з онлайн-спілкування:

  > ***Народ**! Я прошу вибачення ...;*

Варіанти "народ" та "люди" в принципі можна застосовувати, звертаючись до змішаної групи молодих людей.

---

Також, в сучасній англійській мові вживаним звереннням до змішаної групи людей є "[you guys](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=you%20guys)" (дослівно: "ви хлопці").

Comment: Ще можна сказати *Товариство!*, *Зібрання!*. Або й просто *Козаки!*, *Козаченьки!*.

Comment: @Yola, ну _Козаки!_ мабуть все ж не дуже підходить до випадку **змішаної** групи, але [отут](https://gazeta.ua/articles/chistota-movlennya/_ak-zvertatisya-do-spivrozmovnika/496108) стверджують, цитую: «До дитини завше нормально було заговорити: "Привіт, козаче". »

Comment: Братва?........

Answer (score 6):

А чим вам не до вподоби слово „молодь“ з відповідним кличним відмінком „мо́лоде“? Наприклад, дорога мо́лоде або шановна мо́лоде! Навмисно поставив наголос на о́, щоби не плутали з прикметником молоде́. У інтернеті можна знайти безліч текстів з цим відмінком. На цьому сайті http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/ наявні інші синоніми до молодь, але, на мою думку, вони недоречні у вашому випадку.

Comment: Своїм одноліткам сказати *молоде* якось не дуже, хіба що жартома

Comment: Тоді мені спадає на думку таке звертання як компаніє, або й навіть кумпаніє, що підкреслить неформальність звертання.

Comment: @АндрійБандура, про "компаніє" це ви дуже добре згадали!

Answer (score 6):

Для того, щоб дати відповідь на це запитання я спершу звернувся до онлайн словника [Глосб](https://uk.glosbe.com/ru/uk/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0) і подивився, що він пропонує:

**Друзі**

> “Схоже, друзі, вам потрібна допомога”,—сказав він, весело усміхаючись.

**Люди**

> Люди, цього б ніколи не трапилось без можливості секвенувати цілий
>   геном!

**Молодь**

> Коли я вже міг ходити на навчання, то зустрів там дуже багато молоді
>   мого віку і з кількома з них подружився.

**Діти** (якщо говоримо про малих дітей)

> У кінці зустрічі діти поділилися своїми почуттями про цей захід.

На одній із сторінок ЖЖ пропонують наступні варіанти:

**Народ, хлопці та дівчата, товариство, шановні**

Форму [СловникUA](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/lofiversion/index.php?t1835.html) пропонує віріант "**людоньки**".

А ще я переглянув Російсько-українські словники. Справді, більшість варіантів відносяться до групи чоловіків (тут і **хлопці**, **хлоп’я́та** тощо). Однак, і тут були варіанти, які б можна використати, коли звертаємося до дітей: **дитинята, малеча**.

Як бачите, переклад цього слова повністю залежить від контексту.